# Angular 1 vs 2 Services State

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, angular-services

I'm converting an app from Angular 1 to Angular 2+. I wanted to try and gain a better understanding of how attributes are handled in the services. For example:

In Angular 1 we have a service defined like this:

```
function MyService(AnotherService) {

  let flags = [];
```

And in Angular 2+ we have the service defined as such:

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService {

    private flags = [];

    constructor(private _anotherService: AnotherService) { }
```

The problem is, we are getting tests that are failing because in Angular 1 it appears that the state of "flags" is reset to an empty array each time the service is injected to a test, while in Angular 2+ the state of "flags" carries over between tests.

I've been playing around with the TypeScript playground to try and determine why this is. In short, how can I get "flags" to reset to an empty array each time the service is injected with Angular 2, as it appears to be doing with the Angular 1 service? Am I correct in assuming that this what is happening?

Thanks!

----- UPDATE -----------

This is what the test looks like

```
fdescribe('Unit: MyService', function () {
  let service;

  beforeEach(function () {
    angular.mock.inject(function (MyService) {
      service = MyService;
    });
  });

  // PASS: For Angular 1 and Angular2+
  it('should exist', function () {
    expect(service).toBeDefined();
  });

  // PASS: For Angular 1 and Angular2+
  it('should create flags', function () {
    let id = 1;
    let property = 'testProperty';
    let value = 'testValue';

    service.setFlags(id, property, value);

    let flags = service.getFlags();

    let foundElement = flags.find((element) => {
      return element.id === id;
    });

    expect(foundElement.property).toBe(value);
  });

  // PASS Angular 1, FAIL Angular 2+
  it('should update flags', function () {
    let id = 1;
    let property = 'testProperty';
    let value = 'testValue';

    service.setFlags(id, property, value);

    let flags = service.getFlags();

    let foundElement = flags.find((element) => {
      return element.id === id;
    });

    let newValue = 'testNewValue';

    service.setFlags(id, property, newValue);

    expect(foundElement.testProperty).toBe(newValue);

  });
```

Comment: Most likely the problem is with how you have set up your tests. Please add it to your question. I personally haven't seen such a behavior in Angular 2+ so far.